# Is it possible to deploy an AllUsers VPN connection to Windows 10 via Group Policy

Tags: vpn, group-policy, windows-10

We currently deploy a per user VPN connection to our Windows 10 clients by running a login PowerShell script to add a user context VPN.

We would like to deploy the same connection as an AllUsers connection, so it is available on the login screen before users sign in. Is it possible to do this via Group Policy only? Will a startup script run under system context and allow this to deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have gone with an approach of:

- Create the VPN as we need it
- Copy the `"rasphone.pbk"` from `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk`
- Use Group Policy Preferences to copy this file from a central location to the same folder on target computers.

This works perfectly in our scenario, but the only thing to bear in mind, is that this will overwrite any existing system wide VPN connections.